# Macros on lines with different structures

Tags: macro

There are occasions where I use macros to re-format multiple lines, where the lines can have a different format. For these tasks, I use appropriate macros, but due to the different formats this can fail. In these cases I might use multiple macros that I then use accordingly to the current line, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

As an example: I was re-formatting the following lines, where I wanted every entry of the lua tables to be on their own line:

```
{ foo = 1, bar = 2 },
{ foo = 42, bar = -4 },
{ foo = 1, bar = 9, baz = "boo" },
```

In this case I'd use a macro that inserts new lines after commas and also puts the closing `}` on its own line (of course some of this can be fixed by fitting `:s` commands, but this is a simple example, these can get more complex.

Is there a good way to tackle these cases? I'd also be happy to use a macro that inserts *one* line but repeats itself until there are no more matches on this line. However, I also would not know how to do that.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a formatter.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the following macro:

```
/\v(,|.})^Ma^M^[
```

And I would call it repeatedly.

Where:

- `^M` stands for <kbd>Enter</kbd> and
- `^[` stands for <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I'd also use something similar, but I usually then after recording a macro use `:norm@a` on a range of lines. It would be nice if the macro could figure out itself how often it needs to be called.

Comment: @pschulz the classic way is a recursive macro where an early or late « go to next occurrence » command can fail (such as searching or the f/t commands), since failures end macro playback.